# Is it possible to connect my iPhone 3G via Bluetooth to both OS on my MacBook?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, bootcamp, bluetooth, tethering

I'm trying to connect my iPhone 3G to my MacBook via Bluetooth to use the iPhone Tethering.
When I connect the iPhone to the OS X everything works fine. Since I often also use Windows 7 on the Boot Camp partition I'd like to connect from Windows 7 to the iPhone as well.

This works, but in this case I always have to remove and reconnect it when booting back to OS X and vice versa.

Is it possible to setup the Bluetooth connection and have it working in both operating systems on the same MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

The bluetooth connection is maintained by the OS (Windows or Mac OS X) so as soon as you restart, the connection is lost and you have to re-establish it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware that I have to re-establish the connection. My problem is if I'm cross booting, the iPhone is not recognized by OSX or Win7.